# How can I route directly to a view without a controller/action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this isn't the purpose of using MVC framework, but can you please tell me how to route root to a html.erb file. The rest of my program has controllers and views, I just need the default page to route a static file.

```
root :to => 'somepage.html.erb'
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the file in `app/views/application/my_html_document.html.erb`. Create the route for it:

```
root to: "application#my_html_document"
```

I typically create a specific controller (ie `PagesController`) for my one-off "static" pages within a site which don't fall under another controller.

Answer (score 1):

check in the `config/routes.rb` file towards the bottom, where it says:

```
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  root :to => "static#index"    # e.g. if you implement a static_controller
```

The easiest way is to make a separate controller for static files, like explained in this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages

That's preferable to directly linking to the html.erb files, because it's easier to extend.

With the static controller, you can easily add pages like `static#somepage`